# How to Mass Delete Files in Windows using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I recently refreshed my PC and upon finally finishing, I realized a pesky file named thumbs.db had been left in every folder and directory. I'm trying to find a simple way to DELETE ALL thumbs.db from my ENTIRE C: drive.

Code I've tried (Only removed thumbs.db from desktop)

```
dir thumbs.db /a /b /s
del thumbs.db /a /s
```

PS: I'm open to any Power Shell Ideas Also.

Comment: In addition to the answer you've received, you may want to disable the creation of thumbs.db in the future. See https://www.sitepoint.com/switch-off-thumbs-db-in-windows/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by running:

```
C:
cd /
del /s /q /f /a:h Thumbs.db
```

The first line sets the drive you want to run it on.
The second line points to the root directory of the drive.
The third line force deletes (/f) hidden (/a:h) thumbs.db without prompting (/q) in all subfolders (/s)

Comment: This command brings up an error: "Could Not Find C:\Thumbs.db" I checked my documents and there is one in there. Same with my other folders. I might point out that the files default hidden in all folders.

Comment: Added a couple more switches to the command to force deletion and specifically look at files marked with the Hidden attribute.

Comment: Works like a charm. Just in some folders, you need to open the deepest directory. The it deletes them all. Marked as answered.